# Cancelar overflow para un elemento específico que está dentro de otro elemento con overflow

Tags: html, css

en primer lugar os pongo en contexto: Se trata de una barra con botones, a la cual se le ha aplicado al div que contiene la barra overflow:hidden para evitar que los botones, al redimensionar la ventana, se muevan para abajo. ¿Cuál es el problema? Que algunos botones, cuando se pasa el cursor sobre ellos, despliega una lista, la cual deja invisible por el overflow:hidden, me gustaría saber cómo poder cancelar el overflow:hidden en un elemento en específico el cual está englobado por un div que tiene la propiedad overflow:hidden, es decir, sería cancelar parcialmente el overflor:hidden para el elemento que quiero. El css que tengo es el siguiente:

El div que contiene la barra principal

```
.menu-nav {
background: #d3d5da url("../images/coltitle_bg.gif") top left repeat-x;
height: 35px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
overflow: hidden;
```

Después hay un ul></ul que contiene los botones (en estilo de elementos de lista), después cada botón es un li></li. Por último, dentro de ese li></li siguiendo el ejemplo de la imagen, el botón de administración, hay un otro li></li que contiene un submenú, y esa es la parte que quiero hacer visible, por lo que entiendo que haya alguna propiedad que pueda cancelar el overflow para ese elemento en específico, manteniéndolo para el resto.

El css del submenú que quiero hacer visible es:

```
.dropmenu li ul {
z-index: 90;
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 19.2em;
font-weight: normal;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
background: url(../images/theme/menu_gfx.png) 0 -130px no-repeat;
padding: 7px 0 0 0;
```

}

[image: imagen del problema]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sería muy grato si también agregaras el HTML para analizar más ampliamente y estudiar el caso

Comment: Buenas @NarcisoAifuz Gracias por responder. El html es muy simple: <div(contenedor)><ul(lista de botones)><li(botón)><li(submenú del botón>
Lo que quiero es romper la regla del overflow:hidden del div contenedor con el <li(submenú>

Comment: Particularmente yo necesito mucho más código para ayudarte tambien. Leete [ask]. (Y no es tocar las narices, sino para evitar que nos de pereza tambien a nosotros ayudarte si tenemos que recrear tu escenario a mano porque a ti tambien te la dio).